# Which Python Version Should I Choose that will be same with the version on Python App Installation in Cpanel Host Account

Tags: python, django, hosting, cpanel

I have fully developed my Django App using Python Version 3.9.1 and after purchasing Cpanel Python Hosting I realized that there was no version 3.9.1 rather the closer version on their Python App Installation was Version 3.9.12.
I am confused on which version to choose that can work perfectly without errors. I have opened a Ticket to their support but no response till now so I need your professional advise.

Comment: Are you seeing any actual errors?

Comment: Bad request any time I try to login using the app user login page, as at the time I selected their recommended version 3.7.12 and conflict on makemigrations

Comment: Then you have a typo in your version numbers in your question...

Comment: 3.7.12? Is your question about downgrading or upgrading? Also why don't you just run, get errors and then solve them? (That's the only answer you will get from people if they only have the information from your question)

Comment: Thinking of upgrading locally before going live but confused

Comment: Please edit your question so it is clear what you want to do, and which versions are involved (right now it says that you want to upgrade from 3.9.1 to 3.9.12, but in your comment you're saying 3.7.12... which is it?)

Comment: I can help you debug your code, but I will need more detail than the one you provided in your question

Comment: @Bruno, No issues with my code. I am saying the Cpanel Host where I am installing Python app has Python version 3.9.12 as the most closer version to mine which is 3.9.1. My question is clearly that, which version of Python Installation should I choose that will match mine.

Comment: Why not install 3.9.12 locally and make sure that your app works locally with it?